# Azure Data Factory Search and Replace tokens in CSV file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory to process a csv file that has over 40 columns. In these fields there can be but not always, one of 10+ tokens that I want to replace.

What is the best way to search through the whole file and replace those tokens with another value? Each token has a different value that I want to replace it with.

I know I can use the replace function on a derived column schema modifier in a dataflow to search and replace for a string on a column by column basis (See below).  This will only allow me to search for one token at a time when I need to search for 10+ tokens and replace with 10+ values.

I also don't want to have to have to create over 40 entries in the derived column schema modifier and I imagine there is a better way to achieve what I am looking  for?

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Example of some field data

e.g "1 Summer Road[<000013>]","[<000013>]","Wokinngton[<000013>][<000010>]Manchester","","","","1 Summer Road[<000013>][<000010>][<000013>][<000010>]Wokington[<000013>][<000010>]Manchester","our clients[<000039>] schedule",

[image]

Comment: You can use a Column Pattern in Derived Column to process all columns, and a regexReplace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#regexReplace) method to replace all the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Joel Cochran: I can see how column pattern can enable me to target all columns. However I'm not sure the regexreplace function will do what I need.
To explain what I mean, each column/field may have no tokens, 1 token or a combination of multiple tokens. Tokens are in the square brackets. Ive added and example to the question.

The example shows a selection of the possible combination of tokens that could be in each field so I need a way to handle these variations if that makes sense?

Comment: @Joel Cochran: Just to repeat, each token has to be replaced by a particular value so {<000010>] has a value it will be replaced by, [<000013>} is to be replaced by a different value etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add column patterns in derived column transformation use case expression to find and replace multiple values at the same time.

**Example:**

1. Source

[image]

2. Derived Column

[image]

Expression:

```
case($$=='A001', 'A01',
 $$=='B001', 'B01',
 $$=='C001', 'C01',
 $$=='D001', 'D01', $$)
```

[image]

Derived column output:

[image]

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar but had to do multiple passes(derived columns)as there can be multiple values in each column too. Thanks